# How do I send notifications for followers of a group when group content is updated?

Tags: 7, flags, notifications

I want to build such functionality that allow the user to follow the other users, and when the followed person is updating the information, the follower can get notified for what they are doing.

I think to build the specified functionality, I can use the Flag module, but for the notification, what kind of modules are good to work with?
I am confused. There are too many modules like notification, or messaging; even the NodeJs module can notify.

Answer (score 0):

Its depend on how regular you want to notify the user. If you want actual real time notification then go for nodejs module. See the documentation and you will get better idea about it.

Answer (score 0):

For my site, I simply use a Rule to decide when the event has occurred, have an action (referencing either the Flag or the OG for who to notify), and then send an email (pushes the messages to the cron and the emails get sent off to the users who are "subscribed")

It was a lightweight and easy way to do achieve something similar to what you have outlined.

Comment: Let me know if you want a step by step guide as an answer, I can do it the way I suggested or with nodeJS.