# Content notification for updates

Tags: rules, organic-groups, notifications

[OG](https://drupal.org/project/og) has a pre-installed rule "OG group content notification" for sending out notifications to group members of new posts.

Is there a similar rule for sending out notifications of updated group posts to group members?

I have read that there might be a way using [Rules](https://drupal.org/project/rules) on [How do I send notifications for followers of a group when group content is updated?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/31101/how-do-i-send-notifications-for-followers-of-a-group-when-group-content-is-updat) but I was not allowed to post a follow-up comment there.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I did not have the Rules UI enabled. Once I enabled it, I was able to see the "OG new content notification (With Message)" rule clearly.  I only need create a copy of this and edit it to my requirements.